# TDD and BDD with mockk for Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, clean-architecture

I'm trying to get difference between for TDD and BDD when developing Android apps with Clean Architecture with UseCase and repositories.

I have written a simple test with login test and using JUnit5 and Mockk. I created login states which are

```
enum class LoginState {
    SUCCESS,
    EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR,
    CREDENTIALS_ERROR
}
```

and has UseCase concrete class which has an interface to mock local or remote repositories.

private val loginRepository: LoginRepository = mockk()

```
private lateinit var loginUseCase: LoginUseCase

@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    clearMocks(loginRepository)
    loginUseCase = LoginUseCase(loginRepository)
}
```

And the test

```
/**
 *  Scenario: Login check with empty fields:
 * * Given I am on the login page
 * * When I enter empty username
 *   And I enter empty password
 *   And I click on the "Login" button
 * * Then I get empty fields error.
 */
@Test
fun `Empty fields result empty fields error`() {

    // Given
    every { loginRepository.login(any(), any()) } returns LoginState.CREDENTIALS_ERROR

    // When
    val expected = loginUseCase.login("", "")

    // Then
    verify(exactly = 0) { loginRepository.login(any(), any()) }
    assertEquals(expected, LoginState.EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR)

}
```

1. When we use verify does this test counts as behavior driven development test, if i had only used assert is it considered TDD?

I also have another test to check if username, i actually didn't get if both username and password should be included in same test, length is between 6 and 10

```
/**
 *  Scenario: Login check with valid length username:
 * * Given I am on the login page
 * * When I enter valid username
 *   And I enter any password
 *   And I click on the "Login" button
 * * Then I get ???
 */
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = ["abcdef", "abcdefgh", "abcabcabcd"])
fun `User name should have between 6 and 10 characters`(userName: String) {

    // Given
    val slot = slot<String>()
    every {
        loginRepository.login(
            capture(slot),
            any()
        )
    } returns (LoginState.CREDENTIALS_ERROR)

    // When
    val expected = loginUseCase.login(userName, "abcdefg")

    // Then
    verify(exactly = 1) { loginRepository.login(slot.captured, any()) }

    assertEquals(expected, LoginState.CREDENTIALS_ERROR)
    assertTrue(slot.captured.length in 6..10)
    confirmVerified(loginRepository)

}
```

1. What state should be returned from this test to check if username is valid? If i return SUCCESS, my implementation can fail if i enter an invalid password with less than 6 chars for instance. If i return CREDENTIALS_ERROR what would i be returning in then section of BDD?
2. In such a scenario should both username and password included in same test?

Comment: What you are trying to do, i think, is to mix 2 different things which should be separated. You should have one project (dll) for writing unit tests (TDD), for verifying Classes and methods. And another project (dll) for automating scenarios (BDD), for verifying overall behavior of application or behavior between multiple services.

Comment: @StefanZivkovic, i'm trying to get how TDD and BDD is involved with each other. Shouldn't have verification in a unit test that to confirm that method(s) of the injected interface is called?

Comment: Here are some articles that may help you to understand Mocking better. I know you asked about the difference between TDD and BDD but it sounds like these articles may still give you some good insight

Comment: .https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/18/from-interaction-based-to-state-based-testing/

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da

Comment: @Andrew thank you very much. I solved how to mock and implement behavioral testing thanks to your answer to other question.

Comment: @Andrew As far as i got when verifying mock interactions and writing user scenarios extends TDD to BDD, right?

Comment: TDD focuses on testing the functionality of a single method at a time (your dependencies here are mocked and return data that  you control so that you can test the logic within that method). BDD focuses more on the overall behavior of an application so the tests are more on the acceptance test level i.e. testing the functionality as the user would see.  You may still mock out a call to a service or repository, but you would be testing through several layers of code. These tests tend to be a bit harder to write and more susceptible to change.

Comment: @Andrew If i use verify with TDD, i mean i write first tests first mock an interface and verify that interface is called, or not called depending on test, is it considered BDD? Or do i have to write user scenarios or other extensions? I can't get what's the difference if it's BDD or DD when iverify behavior of mocks in a test?

Comment: Mocking does not define the difference between TDD and BDD.  The scope of what  you are testing does. What you are talking about is the difference between state based and interaction based testing. You should prefer state based testing when possible.  With state based testing you will mock a method on a dependency that is called within the method you are testing and return a result from that method to test some expected behavior of the method under test. With interaction based testing you may have a void method on your dependency. The best you can do here is verify that method was called.